# Decode Html5 Audio fast without using "createMediaElementSource"

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I am using the Webaudio api's "createMediaElementSource" which works fine on Firefox(Gecko) and Chrome(Blink) but not Safari(Webkit). This is a big problem for me since I prefer getting the audio from my Html5 audio players rather than using XMLHttpRequests due to the latter being too slow.

The first attempt I did was to get the source as a string from the audio tag and serve it as an url in an XMLHttpRequest. As expected it works but the decoding is very slow and I cant pause the audio with stop() as a resume induces another round of prior decoding of the entire file before it can be heared..

A stackoverflow user named **Kevin Ennis** gave me an important advice which is a really great idea:

> You could break the audio up into a number of smaller files. Like,
>   maybe break it up into 4 separate 1MB audio files and load them in
>   order. Then you can start playback after the first one loads, and
>   while that's playing, you load the other ones.

My question is, how do I do this technically? I am not aware of any function that checks if an audio file finished.

I imagine it would look something like this:

```
    var source = document.getElementByTagName["audio"][0].src;
    var fileExt = source.indexOf('.');
    var currentFile = 1;

    if(decodeCurrentData == complete) {
        currentFile += 1;
        source = source.slice(0, fileExt) + "_part" + currentFile.toString() + ".mp3";
        loadAudioFile();
    }

        var loadAudioFile = function () {
              var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
              request.open( "GET", "source", true );
              request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
              request.onload = function (){
                context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function (buffer) {
                  convolver.buffer = buffer;
                });
              };
              request.send();
            };
     loadAudioFile();
```

Will my idea work or would it utterly fail? What would you suggest I do about the long decoding time?

Comment: You don't need to check if it finished - you just need to schedule ahead to when it should complete.  (That's the only way to get sample-accurate scheduling anyway, which you'll need with this approach.)  Also, I'd point out you'll need to be careful - MP3 decoding sometimes pads the length, depending on the decoder, and it will be different on different systems.

Comment: And decodeAudioData is specified to resample so if the file sample rate doesn't match the context sample rate, the pieces that used to fit together nicely may not fit smoothly anymore.